# HTML video tag not working with safari (tried almost every solution)

Tags: html, video, safari, tags, autoplay

I am trying to add a background video in my project, everything was fine until a month ago and after that I realized than safari won't play the video.

I also have no problem that safari shows an image of the video like a cover but unfortunately, safari shows a play button in the middle of the video so it is not usable at all[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcKhd.png)

I am about to give up at this, so i appreciate any final helps :)

HTML :

```
<video autoplay muted playsinline loop class="bg-video__content">
                        <source src="img/map2.webm" type="video/webm">
                        Your browser is not supported
</video>
```

adding playsinline, muted, ...
I tried almost every possible formats like mp4, mov ...
I even tried formats with different type properties.
I also tried changing the css but nothing happend.

Comment: Hi, does [the link to the background video of the Model-Y](https://www.gomasuga.com/blog/best-practices-for-html-background-videos) here work for you in Safari? Are we talking Safari iOS or Safari MacOS?

Comment: Hello, thnx for the response. No, Model-Y video also does not work and I am talking about safari macOS

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache and cookies of the page?